How to build and install python file in Dockerfile?
I'm writing a Dockerfile but I cannot install a python setup file.
This is my code [Dockerfile]:
FROM nvcr.io/nvidia/pytorch:22.12-py3
# 24.03-py3: cuda version 12.4
# FROM nvcr.io/nvidia/pytorch:24.03-py3

# Define variables
ENV PROJECT_NAME mov
ENV PYTHON_VER 3.10
ENV ROOT_PASSWORD 11111
# Create a non-root user
ENV USER_NAME=user
ARG USER_PASSWORD=$ROOT_PASSWORD

# /home/$USER_NAME/anaconda3
ENV CONDA_DIR /home/$USER_NAME/anaconda3 

# Install some packages
RUN apt update
# Change the download server
COPY sources.list /etc/apt/sources.list
RUN apt update

RUN apt install -y wget sudo git
# Timezone pre-setting for other installation if they ask the timezone
ENV DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive
RUN apt install -y tzdata
RUN ln -fs /usr/share/zoneinfo/Asia/Seoul /etc/localtime && \
    dpkg-reconfigure -f noninteractive tzdata
# Base
RUN apt install -y build-essential vim screen
RUN apt install -y libgl1-mesa-glx ffmpeg libsm6 libxext6
# For Anaconda
RUN apt install -y libegl1-mesa libxrandr2 libxrandr2 
RUN apt install -y libxss1 libxcursor1 libxcomposite1 
RUN apt install -y libasound2 libxi6 
RUN apt install -y libxtst6 libglib2.0-0

# User setting with password
RUN adduser --disabled-password --gecos "" $USER_NAME  \
    && echo "$USER_NAME:$USER_PASSWORD" | chpasswd \
    && adduser $USER_NAME sudo \
    && echo "$USER_NAME ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD:ALL" >> /etc/sudoers
USER $USER_NAME

# Set the working directory
WORKDIR /home/$USER_NAME/workspace
# Copy your application code into the container
COPY ./moving_ai /home/$USER_NAME/workspace

# Install anaconda
RUN sudo wget https://repo.anaconda.com/archive/Anaconda3-2022.10-Linux-x86_64.sh -O anaconda.sh
RUN sudo chmod +x anaconda.sh 
RUN ./anaconda.sh -b -p $CONDA_DIR
RUN sudo rm anaconda.sh  
RUN sudo apt clean  
RUN sudo rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/* /tmp/* /var/tmp/*

# Update conda, create a new environment, and install OpenCV
RUN $CONDA_DIR/bin/conda update -n base -c defaults conda
RUN $CONDA_DIR/bin/conda create -n $PROJECT_NAME python=$PYTHON_VER
RUN $CONDA_DIR/bin/conda init

# Set the environment variable for Anaconda installation
ENV PATH $CONDA_DIR/bin:$PATH

# Reload the .bashrc file
# To load base conda
RUN /bin/bash -c "source ~/.bashrc || true"

# activate conda
RUN echo "conda activate $PROJECT_NAME" >> ~/.bashrc
RUN /bin/bash -c "source ~/.bashrc || true"

RUN /bin/bash -c "source activate $PROJECT_NAME && \
    pip install Flask-Cors jupyter wandb opencv-python chardet pandas matplotlib scikit-learn flask bcrypt pymysql seaborn"

# Install PyTorch
RUN /bin/bash -c "source activate $PROJECT_NAME && \
    pip install torch torchvision torchaudio --index-url https://download.pytorch.org/whl/cu118"


# Copy your application code into the container
COPY ./requirements.txt /home/$USER_NAME/workspace

# Install any needed dependencies specified in requirements.txt
RUN /bin/bash -c "source activate $PROJECT_NAME && \
    pip install --no-cache-dir -r requirements.txt"


# After pytorch
RUN /bin/bash -c "source activate $PROJECT_NAME && \
    pip install torcheval efficientnet_pytorch paramiko"

# Copy the files and set permissions/ownership in a single step
COPY --chown=$USER_NAME:$USER_NAME ./moving_ai /home/$USER_NAME/workspace/moving_ai


# Install dependencies and run unit tests
RUN test -d /home/$USER_NAME/workspace/moving_ai/DINO/models/dino/ops && \
    rm -rf /home/$USER_NAME/workspace/moving_ai/DINO/models/dino/ops || true
RUN cd /home/$USER_NAME/workspace/moving_ai && \
    cp -r dino_ops/ops DINO/models/dino/ops

RUN cd /usr/local/cuda
# Verify environment variables
RUN echo "CUDA_HOME: $CUDA_HOME"
RUN echo "PROJECT_NAME: $PROJECT_NAME"
RUN echo "USER_NAME: $USER_NAME"
# To load environment variables
RUN /bin/bash -c "source ~/.bashrc || true"

# Run
RUN $CONDA_DIR/bin/activate mov && \
    cd /home/$USER_NAME/workspace/moving_ai && \
    cd DINO/models/dino/ops && \
    python setup.py build install

I received the error:
=> ERROR [43/43] RUN /home/user/anaconda3/bin/activate mov &&     cd /home/user/workspace/moving_ai &&     cd DINO/models/dino/ops &&     python setup.py build install        1.6s
------
 > [43/43] RUN /home/user/anaconda3/bin/activate mov &&     cd /home/user/workspace/moving_ai &&     cd DINO/models/dino/ops &&     python setup.py build install:
#0 1.404 No CUDA runtime is found, using CUDA_HOME='/usr/local/cuda'
#0 1.404 Traceback (most recent call last):
#0 1.404   File "/home/user/workspace/moving_ai/DINO/models/dino/ops/setup.py", line 72, in <module>
#0 1.404     ext_modules=get_extensions(),
#0 1.404   File "/home/user/workspace/moving_ai/DINO/models/dino/ops/setup.py", line 38, in get_extensions
#0 1.404     raise NotImplementedError('torch.cuda.is_available() is False')
#0 1.404 NotImplementedError: torch.cuda.is_available() is False
------
Dockerfile:138
--------------------
 137 |     # # Run
 138 | >>> RUN $CONDA_DIR/bin/activate mov && \
 139 | >>>     cd /home/$USER_NAME/workspace/moving_ai && \
 140 | >>>     cd DINO/models/dino/ops && \
 141 | >>>     python setup.py build install
 142 |     
--------------------
ERROR: failed to solve: process "/bin/sh -c $CONDA_DIR/bin/activate mov &&     cd /home/$USER_NAME/workspace/moving_ai &&     cd DINO/models/dino/ops &&     python setup.py build install" did not complete successfully: exit code: 1

But if I remove the last part "python setup.py build install" and make the docker, it works well. And then execute "python setup.py build install" in the running container, it works well either.
Please help me to fix this problem.
